# Oracle Memory error while using updatexml on xmltype column with more than 1 million rows

Tags: oracle, xmltype, updatexml

I have a script to update the xmltype specific nodes as part of masking the data. While running the update using updatexml function of Xmltype column getting memory error in oracle.

```
Update table1 
set xmlcolum = updatexml(xmlcolumn,’/row/c41/text()’,’Mask’)
```

Total rows in that table is 1,154,720

> Ora-04030: out of process memory while trying to allocate 33584 bytes

Comment: Guess a bad design (storing data as strings instead of proper tables) reached the meltdown point. 1M rows isn't a lot for *any* database. All commercial databases offer strong masking features for at least 10 years. Using XML to avoid creating proper tables is simply bad

Comment: In any case, there's not a lot of information except the modest row count and the obvious memory fragmentation that prevented the database from allocating even 32KB. How big is each XML string? Which database version are you using? Perhaps there's a patch to fix the fragmentation issue. As a workaround you could update the data in batches, eg 1000 at a time. The real solution though would be to fix the bad database design. Otherwise you'll keep running into issues

Comment: Unfortunately the entire table was built as string stored in Xmltype. We are thinking for breaking down into 100000 recs per update

Comment: Yes, that was unfortunate. And must be fixed, replaced with a proper database design. What's the point of using Oracle if you treat it as a file system? You lose all the performance features a database offers, like indexing. And the detailed security features like row/column-level security or masking. Batching is only a quick-fix, allowing you to complete the current operation. It won't prevent further problems. Patching is only a stop-gap, just to prevent crashes. You'll still have serious performance problems